# Is "I go for Avatar" as the most horrible movie acceptable?

Tags: idioms

When someone asks "What is the most horrible movie you ever watched?" which one is more correct as an answer?

> I go for Avatar.
>
> I will go for Avatar.

Is there any other better-suited answer?

Comment: All that's necessary is _Avatar_. Both your answers are acceptable in speech because they're understandable. But maybe native speakers would prefer something like "I vote for _Avatar_".

Comment: Normally I say "I'd go for something" if I am given a finite list of choices, which is not the case here.

Comment: You could also say, and perhaps more likely, "I'll go with Avatar."

Comment: As a native speaker in this context of open choice, I would say either just "Avatar." or "It's got to be Avatar". I wouldn't say any of the examples here in this context, unless choosing between X and Y. In the case of a defined choice, "I will choose" or "I will go for" would be correct, like FF's response.

Comment: I'd say "I'm going to have to go with Avatar" or simply "I'd say Avatar"

Answer (score 4):

A native speaker would say something more like:

> "I say, *Avatar*."

or maybe:

> "I'd nominate *Avatar*."

The two-word expression *go for* can indeed mean "to choose or decide on," but I don't think I'd use it in the context you mention. For one thing, "go for" generally has a positive connotation, so it sounds especially awkward when using it when selecting the "most horrible" movie ever watched.

I'm trying to think of a conversation where a similar expression would be used in a similar context. The best I can think of at the moment is:

> "What's the worst movie you've ever watched?"
>   "I'd say, *Avatar*."
>   "Oh, *Avatar* awful. I could go along with that."

but, in that case, *go along with* means *agree with*, not *decide upon.*

Using *go for* to mean *choose* would work better if the question is less open-ended, and the speaker has only a few options. I'm imagining someone going through a cafeteria line:

> "And what can I get for you?"
>   "I think I'll go for the fish."

Comment: Nah. I'd go for my answer! :)

Answer (score 3):

From the OED entry for verb **to go [for]**

> To have for one's aim; to aim at securing; †also = the later go in for (see to go in at Phrasal verbs 1). In recent use also with stronger sense (cf. 2e), to concentrate effort on the attainment of (an object). Also, to be enamoured of or **enthusiastic about**; to care for, like, or prefer; to **choose**, accept, or **support**.

---

As regards whether to use present or future tense, it's really just a matter of personal choice:

> Q: *"Do you want A or B?"*
>     A1: *"I **choose** A"*
>    A2: *"I **will choose** A"* (often articulated as *"**I'll choose** A"*
>   A3: *"I **would choose** A"* (often articulated as *"**I'd choose** A"*)

For most contexts, all tenses convey exactly the same meaning, as do various alternative verbs. In OP's exact context, *go for, pick, say,* for example, would all work. In my example, *have, take*, etc., would also work if, say, A and B were two alternative meals being offered by a waiter in a restaurant.

You can see all the answers as ["self-embodying"](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/45627/2637) statements (you're *making* your choice by *saying* it), so logically it might seem A1 is the most appropriate. But in fact it's probably the least likely form. Also note that most Anglophones would *never* say *"I **am choosing**"* (though I suspect speakers of "Indian English" might well tend to use that form).

A3 *I would* might seem logically "strange" (since you *are* choosing, there's nothing "conditional" about it), but that is in fact the most likely verb form in almost all such contexts.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the "I am choosing" part? Even though it sounds odd I would still like to know the reason?

Comment: @Batman: I'm not an expert on Indian English, so I'm not even *sure* they'd be likely to use (or accept without demural) present continuous in such contexts. It just "sounds Indian" to me. But "mainstream" Anglophones certainly wouldn't, because we normally only use that tense for *actions which are continuous over some time*, from past through present, continuing into the future. Which doesn't really apply to OP's context of expressing a choice.